# AWS Lambda: SES not working when Lex Chatbot is published to Slack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, slack-api

`AWS SES` works with `Lex` Test Chatbot but after the chatbot is published with Slack app it does not work( doesn't trigger email service). However there does not seem to be any problem with `Lambda` function as I am getting the response text back in slack. And i don't think there is a way to check the error why slack is making the problem.

`Lambda` Function:

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var ses = new aws.SES({
  region: 'us-east-1'
});

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {

  var eParams = {
    Destination: {
      ToAddresses: [event.currentIntent.slots.Email]
    },
    Message: {
      Body: {
        Text: {
          Data: "Hi, How are you?"
        }
      },
      Subject: {
        Data: "Title"
      }
    },

    Source: "abc@gmail.com"
  };
  var email = ses.sendEmail(eParams, function(err, data) {
    if (err)
    else {

      context.succeed(event);

    }
  });

  callback(null, {
    "dialogAction": {
      "type": "ConfirmIntent",
      "fulfillmentState": "Fulfilled",
      "message": {
        "contentType": "PlainText",
        "content": "message to convey to the user, i.e. Are you sure you want a large pizza?"
      }
    }
  });
};
```

Edit 1: I figured the issue is that i am not getting the values in `[event.currentIntent.slots.Email]` when i publish my `Lex` bot on `Slack`.

Comment: I think there is a way check the error when you are calling `ses.sendEmail(...)`, you should log the error in your callback, i.e. `if (err) { logError(err); } ...`, this may very well explain why the email is not sending.

Comment: @ARJMP I figured the issue is that i am not getting the values in '[event.currentIntent.slots.Email]' when i publish my Lex bot on Slack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to below steps to identify the root cause:

1. Make sure you have configured your bot with Slack correctly with [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/slack-bot-association.html) step-by-step tutorial.
2. If your bot works fine in your test bot (inside LEX) but not on Slack make sure you have **published the latest version** of your bot.
3. Try this below code on your AWS Lambda and see what you get in return.

   `callback(null, {
     "dialogAction": {
       "type": "ConfirmIntent",
       "fulfillmentState": "Fulfilled", 
       "message": {
         "contentType": "PlainText",
         "content": "Echo: " + JSON.stringify(event.currentIntent.slots) <-- This
       }
     }
   });`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where the bot worked in the lex console but not in slack.  While unrelated to email this is what I discovered.

For some reason an empty session attributes 
is stored as `NULL` when passed to slack.  Thus you can't add variables to it. You'd expect it to be `{}` so if it is `NULL` change it's value to `{}`

```
if(intentRequest.sessionAttributes == null){ 
    intentRequest.sessionAttributes = {};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the above comment, this was what got my slack bot to line up with what my test lex chat was doing:

```
session_attributes = intent_request['sessionAttributes'] if intent_request['sessionAttributes'] is not None else {}
```